# What is the difference between Static and Dynamic in Data Structure

Tags: data-structures

I want to know the clear cut difference between static and dynamic in C#.
I have seen many posts on different blogs but i was not satisfied by their answers .

Please explain me clearly.

Comment: Static or dynamic what?  which language?  Is this a specific coding question or general curiosity?  As it stands now, your question is not answerable.

Comment: Its a general curiosity

Answer (score 0):

These terms are used in a number of ways, depending on the specific context. But in general, *static* refers to something that's specified early, or hard-coded into a program, and is not easily changed. *Dynamic* refers to something that's intended to be updated on the fly.

For instance, in C, if you declare an array like:

```
int arr[100];
```

the size of the array is static: it's always 100 elements. Even if you use a macro, like this:

```
int arr[SIZE];
```

you would have to update the macro definition and recompile the program to change the array's size. The compiler will set aside a fixed block of memory to hold the array; if it's a local variable, it will allocate the memory in the stack frame of the function, if it's a global variable it will be allocated at program start-up time in the BSS segment (the specific details are implementation-dependent, but this is the typical way).

On the other hand, if you use:

```
int *arr = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

the array's size is dynamic -- it depends on the current value of the variable `n`, which can depend on program inputs and other state. You can also use `realloc()` to change the array's size.

Comment: how memory is allocated in static and dynamic?